# After installing heroku using npm install -g heroku-cli in Windows 8.1, I'm getting this error on heroku --version

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt, heroku-cli

After installing heroku using npm install -g heroku-cli in Windows 8.1, I'm getting this error on heroku --version

```
C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\heroku-cli\node_modules\cli-eng
ine\lib\cli.js:70
async run() {

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\hero
ku-cli\bin\run.js:2:34)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Heroku CLI requires node >=7.10.0 or greater

Answer (score 0):

Go to the [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/) website and download the latest version (Now: v8.1.2 Current).

After installation test the Heroku Toolbelt by using the version command in your command line interface:

```
> heroku version
```